# Apply a debugger visualizer without assembly dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debuggervisualizer

I am trying to create a debug visualizer which applies to a variety of objects
without make the visualizer assembly a dependency.  I want to apply this visualizer to a variety of classes, including private nested, internal, and with lots of complex generics involved (both of the parent and nested classes).  This means I'm creating a proxy object with only the critical data involved.

I don't want my main assembly to have a dependency on the visualizer assembly, and I don't want the visualizer assembly to know about the guts of the main assembly.

In the main assembly, I have something that looks like this:

```
namespace MainAsm
{
    public interface IVisualizable
    {
        DebugProxy DebugVisualizer { get; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class DebugProxy
    {
        // data required for visualization here

        public DebugProxy() { }
        public DebugProxy(IVisualizable source)
        {
            var orig = source.DebugVisualizer;
            // copy properties from orig
        }
    }
}
```

Then for the visualizer, I have code that looks like this:

```
[assembly:System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(
    typeof(dbg.Visualizer),
    typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.VisualizerObjectSource),
    TargetTypeName="MainAsm.DebugProxy, MainAsm",
    Description="MainAsm Debug Visualizer")]

namespace dbg
{
    public class Visualizer : Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        protected override void Show(
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.IDialogVisualizerService windowService,
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            object data = objectProvider.GetObject();
            if (data == null)
                return;
            var t = data.GetType();
            var prop = t.GetProperty("DebugVisualizer");
            if (prop != null)
            {
                data = prop.GetValue(data, null) ?? data;
            }

            // use reflection to grab additional properties and open a window
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to apply a visualizer to any class which knows how to create a DebugProxy.  I can obviously get a visualizer if I expand an object and click on its DebugVisualizer property, but I want the visualization to be associated with the top level object.  So if I have something like this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(???)]
public class MyClass<TThis, T2, T3> : IVisualizable
    where TThis : MyClass<TThis, T2, T3>, new()
    where T2 : SomeOtherClass2<T2, T3>, new()
    where T3 : SomeOtherClass3<T2, T3>, new()
{
    DebugProxy IVisualizable.DebugVisualizer { get { return CreateProxy(); } }
}
```

The question is, what do I need to put in place of ??? to get it associate a visualizer with MyClass<,,> and its descendants?

--

- If I put **[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(DebugProxy))]** the DebugProxy doesn't show up with a visualizer icon
- If I put **[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer("dbg.Visualizer")]**, I get a *NullReferenceException* at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebugViewerShim.ManagedShim.DelegateHost.CreateViewer
- If I put **[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer("dbg.Visualizer, dbg")]**, I get "*Could not load file or assembly dbg or one of its dependencies*" even though the log shows the correct path under "Initial PrivatePath = " when it tries to resolve the assembly.
- If I put **[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer("dbg.Visualizer", "Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.VisualizerObjectSource")]**, I get "*Cannot create Visualizer Object Source.*"  The call stack is a series of methods in DebuggerVisualizeres.DebugViewerShim namespace: "DelegatedHost.CreateViewer" -> "PrivateCallback.MaybeDeserializeAndthrowException" -> "DebugeeHost.CreateSourceInternal" -> "RemoteObjectSourceException"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is to create a customized VisualizerObjectSource and put that into the GAC:

```
namespace dbg
{
    public class CustomObjectSource
        : Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.VisualizerObjectSource
    {
        private static object ConvertObject(object oldObj)
        {
            if (oldObj == null)
                return null;
            foreach (var intf in oldObj.GetType().GetInterfaces())
            {
                var prop = intf.GetProperty("DebugVisualizer");
                if (prop != null)
                    return prop.GetValue(oldObj, null);
            }
            return oldObj;
        }

        public override void TransferData(object target, Stream incomingData, Stream outgoingData)
        {
            base.TransferData(ConvertObject(target), incomingData, outgoingData);
        }

        public override object CreateReplacementObject(object target, Stream incomingData)
        {
            return ConvertObject(base.CreateReplacementObject(ConvertObject(target), incomingData));
        }

        public override void GetData(object target, Stream outgoingData)
        {
            base.GetData(ConvertObject(target), outgoingData);
        }
    }
}
```

Then put the following attribute on the classes that implement IVisualizable:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(
    "dbg.Visualizer, dbg, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=???",
    "dbg.CustomObjectSource, dbg, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=???"]
```

Where ??? is the public key of the assembly.

It's very important that the assembly with CustomObjectSource goes into the GAC, because this ensures that it can be loaded into the debugee app domain no matter what its base path is set as.  Make sure it has a strong name and use "gacutil /f /i dbg.dll" from a Visual Studio command prompt to install it.

Then when you try to visualize your class, it will load CustomObjectSource into your app domain, use the CreateReplacementObject method to convert it to the serializable type, and perform the serialization on the DebugProxy object instead of the original type.